# Buildozer failing with pip dependencies, 'no valid dependency graph'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, kivy, buildozer

I'm attempting to compile a kivy app for android using the python3crystax recipe. When building only with recipes listed in python-for-android, it compiles fine, but whenever I attempt to add a pip dependency, it fails with this error:

```
[ERROR]:   Didn't find any valid dependency graphs.
[ERROR]:   This means that some of your requirements pull in conflicting dependencies.
[ERROR]:   Exiting.
```

When using the python2 recipe, however, it compiles fine. Does python3crystax support installing dependencies over pip?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your dependency does have a recipe, but that the recipe isn't marked as python3crystax compatible. Give more information about what you're attempting if you want a more specific answer.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to have been the case. I was attempting to install the requests package. Fortunately, I was able to workaround the problem by using p4a's master branch as opposed to the stable and using the new python3 recipe.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to workaround this issue by changing the python-for-android branch that buildozer uses from stable to master in my buildozer.spec file. This gave me access to the new python3 recipe and that seems to be working fine.